# Having some trouble properly displaying Custom Post Types in templates

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, theme-development, templates, child-theme

I have a child theme of Twenty Thirteen and I've setup Custom Post Types for several items.  They are showing up in the Dashboard, I can create the Custom Posts and they show up in various categories because I called the `$query->set()` with the Custom Post Types.  I've saved and re-saved Permalinks many times to flush the rewrites.

Here is how I registered one in `functions.php`...

```
$labels_successstories = array(
    // my various labels are in here
);  
$args_successstories = array(
    'labels' => $labels_successstories,
    'public' => true,
    'menu_position' => 29,
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' ),
    'taxonomies' => array( 'category' ),
    'has_archive' => 'success-stories',
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'success-stories' )
);  
register_post_type( 'successstories', $args_successstories );
```

In Settings > Permalinks > Custom Structure >

```
/%category%/%postname%/
```

Here is how I call `$query->set()` in `functions.php`

```
function get_custom_posts( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && empty($query->query_vars['suppress_filters']) ) { // is not in Dashboard (is_admin => Dashboard)       
        if ( is_home() ) {  // home page - show only animal posts
            return $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'successstories', 'another-post-type' ) );
        } else if ( is_search() ) {  // search page - show only posts, pages and custom post types
            return $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'page', 'successstories', 'another-post-type' ) );
        } else if ( ! is_single() ) { // everything else, EXCEPT for Singles, show everything
            return $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'page', 'attachment', 'successstories', 'another-post-type' ) );
        }
    } 
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'get_custom_posts' );
```

My goal is to remove as many Categories as I can since the Custom Post Types will effectively replace most of these Categories.  However, one of my Custom Post Types will still need a few Categories.

Here are the questions/issues:

1)  When I go to `mysite.com/success-stories/`, it's using the default `archive.php` template.  However, I have created a template called `archive-successstories.php` and it's being totally ignored.  (if it matters, the `single-successstories.php` template is working perfectly fine)

2)  When I go to `mysite.com/success-stories/`, I see posts but they're coming from all posts, custom post types, and categories.  I just want to see posts from the `successstories` Custom Post Type when I go there.  I think I know how to fix this but if the archive template is being ignored, then my fix will not be seen.

3)  Right now, Success Stories (Custom Post Types) are also in a Category named `success-stories` which can be accessed at `mysite.com/category/success-stories` and that shows the correct posts.  However, my goal is to remove this Category since it's not needed.  Once I get these Custom Post Types to show on their proper archive pages, the respective Categories will be superfluous.

Comment: You should be checking for `$query->is_main_query()` in your filter, otherwise it will apply to all queries, including secondary ones everywhere. It's hard to guess without rebuilding your setup completely, but having same slugs for different things in WP is typical to cause issues.

Comment: @Rarst, thank-you for the suggestion.  Now I have `if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && empty($query->query_vars['suppress_filters']) ) {` but the problems remain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole problem was in my filters.  The last one was a catch-all for everything not already defined...

```
} else if ( ! is_single() ) { // everything else, EXCEPT for Singles, show everything
    return $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'page', 'attachment', 'successstories', 'another-post-type' ) );
}
```

I fixed all three issues by adding `(! is_archive())` to this last conditional...

```
} else if ( (! is_single()) && (! is_archive()) ) {
    return $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'page', 'attachment', 'successstories', 'another-post-type' ) );
}
```

- archive templates are now being found
- only posts from the respective Custom Post Type are being displayed in the archive
- there are no conflicts with any category sharing the same slug name. (*although I'll still be removing these because they're now redundant and superfluous.*)

**EDIT**:

Now that I've cleaned up the taxonomy, removed superfluous categories, that whole `else if ( (! is_single()) && (! is_archive()) )` is not even needed.  Thanks Chip for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Three questions per post is not typical; however, as they may all be inter-related I'll try to help step through each one in turn.

The first problem may be simple:

> When I go to mysite.com/success-stories/, it's using the default
>   archive.php template. However, I have created a template called
>   archive-successstories.php and it's being totally ignored.

The use of the archive template is determined by the `'has_archve'` parameter in your `register_post_type()` call, which you've added like so:

```
'has_archive' => 'success-stories'
```

However, [per the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments), `'has_archive'` is expected to be `string/boolean`: i.e. `true` or `false`. Try this instead:

```
'has_archive' => true
```

Then, flush your rewrite rules by loading the `Settings -> Permalinks` page.

**Important note**: The URL to display the CPT archive using `archive-successstories.php` will be `example.com/successstories`, *not* `example.com/success-stories`. If you want to use the latter, you'll need to pass a valid `'rewrite'` parameter to `register_post_type()`. Note that `'rewrite'`, if not `boolean`, must be an **array**, not a **string**.

Comment: Not true, `has_archive` does accept string slug for archive `$archive_slug = $args->has_archive === true ? $args->rewrite['slug'] : $args->has_archive;`

Comment: Indeed, but only if you add the appropriate rewrite rules, if the string passed is different from the CPT slug. In this case: `'success-stories' != 'successstories'`. By passing `true` to `has_archive`, `example.com/successstories` will properly display `archive-successstories.php`.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "only if you add", it's handled automatically. Saying that `has_archive` only accepts `true/false` is incorrect. It accepts `true/false` **or** archive's slug for rewrite. Also from quick look template hierarchy uses post type name for template file name, it doesn't look at rewrite settings.

Comment: Ultimately, I think the issue lies somewhere in the conflation/mixture of `successstories` and `success-stories`. Making the slug consistent throughout will (probably) resolve the problem.

Comment: Yeah, but it's more likely clash with same slug category, CPT register doesn't look problematic to me here.

Comment: I read the Codex the same as @Rarst describes here.  If it helps, I have other CPT's where the slug is exactly the same as the CPT name and there are the same issues.

Comment: @Rarst, do you have any idea why my custom archive template is being ignored here?

Comment: Refer back to your issue #3, where you have a category term the same as your CPT slug. Rarst may be onto something there, as well.

Comment: Chip and @Rarst, I deleted the `success-stories` category and re-saved Permalinks... the issue remains.  Now without that category, I have no way to view the Success Stories, until the issue is resolved.

Comment: Also, just for the heck of it, I removed my `'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'success-stories' )` and changed my `'has_archive'` into `true`.  The new archive path show up at `/successstories/` with all post types and the page is still ignoring the custom template.

Comment: Chip and @Rarst, the problem is somewhere in the filters function I've shown in my OP.  Only when I remove them all, the custom archive template is found.

Comment: Shouldn't make a difference, but  `pre_get_posts` is an *action*, not a *filter*. Try `add_action()` instead of `add_filter()`.

Comment: As @rarst already pointed out: you need to add `$query->is_main_query()` to your conditional check, so that you target only the *main* query. Also, get in the habit of appending `$query->` to all your query conditionals, just to be safe. e.g. `$query->is_home()` or `$query->is_single()`. Finally: `if ( ! $query->is_single() ) { // Add all the post-types }` is probably going to cause some...unintended consequences.

Comment: Chip, regarding your Important Note:  I'm already showing `'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'success-stories' )` in my code. Perhaps you missed it, otherwise, maybe I'm misunderstanding you?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't [you add support for registering custom taxonomy types](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73587/how-to-structure-wordpress-for-an-organization-and-its-departments/128544#128544) rather than use categories with your CPT's?

Looks like you have issues because you're using exactly the same slugs for categories or something else which conflict with your CPT names.

You only need has_archive if you want to use a custom archive-cpt.php template otherwise WordPress generates a standard archive.

This is the line which you need to use a custom archive template for your CPT. Removed, an archive will still be generated for your CPT:

```
'has_archive'  => true,
```

You will need this line if using register_taxonomy with your CPT.

If your CPT is named portfolio, you add the above line to your code to register the CPT and the name of the CPT to the custom archive template which, in this case would be:

```
archive-portfolio.php
```

Comment: Thanks Brad but the whole problem was being caused by my filtering. You _are_ allowed to have the same category slug as the custom post type slug. It worked fine after I fixed the filtering issue. However, I still removed those categories because they became redundant.

Comment: Also, if you read the Codex, you will see that `has_archive` can also be a string and it **must** match the slug if you're also using the `rewrite` option as I am.  This is what I've done and it's working now that I've fixed the filtering problem.