# How do I share categories across multiple post types?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I have three custom post types in my theme, and each of them have categories enabled. I want these post types to share the categories between them, so that when adding a category to one, the others get it as well. Is there a way to do this easily?

Comment: Did you try [`register_taxonomy_for_object_type()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy_for_object_type) or something else?

Comment: There is when using register_taxonomy http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73587/how-to-structure-wordpress-for-an-organization-and-its-departments/128544#128544