# Page-CPT.php redirects to archive or single.php

Tags: custom-post-types

I have set up a custom post type called cpt_top_ten_list. I am trying to set up a page to display all of my custom post types.

I've named my new page page-top-ten.php, and added a template tag at the top of the page. Created a page in the dashboard called 'Top Ten List' and assigned that page my new template.

Now when I go to the page it seems to redirect me to an archives page of the custom post type. If  I turn off archive capabilities for the cpt it redirects me to page.php.

If I add `flush_rewrite_rules();` into functions.php, my new custom page works but none of the other pages work. When I take out the `flush_rewrite_rules();` all the pages work except my cpt.

I've tried refreshing my permalink settings by going into the page and re-saving out my settings.

I'm confused as to what is going on here. Why wouldn't my cpt page being recognized as such? Its very strange.

```
function register_top_10_list_custom_post_type() {
        // All the labels
        $names  = array(
            'name' => 'Top 10 List',
            'singular_name' => 'Top 10 List',
            'add_new' => 'Add New List',
            'add_new_item' => 'Add New List',
            'edit_item' => 'Edit List',
            'new_item' => 'New List',
            'all_items' => 'All Lists',
            'view_item' => 'View List',
            'search_items' => 'Search Lists',
            'not_found' =>  'No lists found',
            'not_found_in_trash' => 'No lists found in Trash', 
            'parent_item_colon' => '',
            'menu_name' => 'Top 10 Lists'
          );
        //CPT's paramters
        $args = array(
            'labels' => $names,
            'public' => true, 
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'show_ui' => true, 
            'show_in_menu' => true, 
            'query_var' => true,
            'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/inc/cpt/images/top-10-icon.png', /* the icon for the custom post type menu */
            'capability_type' => 'post',

            'has_archive' => true, 
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'menu_position' => null,
            'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tag'),
            'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' )
        ); 
    //register CPT
    register_post_type( 'cpt_top_ten_list', $args );
}
//initiate CPT
add_action( 'init', 'register_top_10_list_custom_post_type' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing this in your code and the names of your [template hierachy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) seems to be wrong.

page-cpt.php relates to a page template and not a CPT archive.

```
'rewrite'      => array( 'slug' => 'top-ten-list', 'with_front' => false ),
```

Assuming you use the slug top-ten-list

You should name your archive template archive-top-ten-list.php

You should name your single CPT template single-top-ten-list.php

[Here's an example](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/128544/9884) of all the correct code which is tested and works you can use as a guide

No need to add flush_rewrite_rules(); as you can simply re-save your Permalinks.

You could also use dashicons rather than adding an image for your menu icon.

You may also consider adding custom taxonomy types which enable you to create categories for your CPT.

Comment: Thanks Brad.

I went back into the dashboard, deleted the page, re-created the page and then re-assigned the page template and it began working as intended. Strange as I had been trying to nail down this problem for the past day or so. Very frustrating to know I could have just deleted and re-created the page from the beginning. 

I am going to go back and re-name my cpt template files as you have suggested to avoid any confusion down the road if another developer were to take over the site. Thanks for the tips!